# re-compile angular directives dynamically

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dynamically-generated

http://jsfiddle.net/RW46a/2/

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='MyController'>
    <button id="addbtn">add dynamic content</button>
    <div id="mycontent">
        <button ng-click='click()'>click here</button><br/>
        <!-- another button will be added here but its ng-click won't work -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My app uses an external dependency that with jQuery adds HTML code directly to the DOM (*sigh*) pretty much as depicted in the fiddle.

I would like to be able to angularize some of the dynamically added code, e.g. add an ng-click directive to a new button that's appended to the "mycontent" div, see comment above.  What is the best way to do this in an angular friendly way?  I tried to make use of $compile but that quickly got hacky.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the fiddle is saying.  The arg is undefined because you are not passing any args.  I still can't quite understand your problem.

Comment: I edited my question and updated the fiddle, see if it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/AnGCs/) shows one of many ways to achieve what you are trying.  Now, I'm not saying this is correct for your situation.  However, without more information it is hard to know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

There is often ways to achieve 'dynamic' DOM manipulation with angular that does not have to do with using `$compile`.  I hope I've given you one idea.

Basically, you can use `ng-show` for the first element and then `ng-repeat` for the rest:

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.click = function() {
    alert('Clicked');
  };

    $scope.add = function() {
       $scope.contentCollection.push(1);
    }

  $scope.contentCollection = [];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='MyController'>
    <button ng-click="add()" id="addbtn">add dynamic content</button>
    <div ng-show="contentCollection.length > 0" ng-repeat="content in contentCollection">
        <button ng-click='click()'>click here</button><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  I understand that this is how to implement it in pure angularjs.  However here I can't (don't want to) modify much of this external dependency.  Basically, I call their API and it refreshes my DOM by adding elements here and there.  Now I want to make these new elements "actionable", e.g. by adding ng-click to them, but obviously I need to tell angular to parse the new DOM again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude) to add the code fragment into the DOM. This will compile the angular elements before loading the html so you can use directives like ng-click.

Note that this will create a new child scope, so you won't have direct access to the controller's scope.

Comment: How would that work?  The DOM is modified dynamically by the external dependency, i.e. when I call one of their APIs, it appends new elements to the tree.  There is no URL or anything to include, unless I'm missing something to what you're suggesting.

Comment: Yea, I guess I misunderstood your use case. It sounds like a strange scenario like applying a Google API to an input box then it adds elements to the DOM that you then want to add an angular directive to. Let me think it through.