# angular dynamically adding contenteditable directive doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, contenteditable, directive

`Runnable CODE:`  [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRaindrop/mDAGU/3/)

I try to dynamically add contenteditable directive to the <div> element when it is double-clicked.
when I put `contenteditable` directive to <div> in the beginning, the `ng-model` still work, but when I remove it and add it dynamically in `ng-dblclick` callback, `ng-model` seams not work anymore.

It's kind of like [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297094/re-compile-angular-directives-dynamically).

but I can't think of a angular-friendly way to finish my work here.
How can I fix this?

### code: html

```
<div ng-app="customControl">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="mainControl">

    <!-- Dynamically adding contenteditable directive : doesn't work -->
    <div name="myWidget" ng-model="userContent" ng-click="enableEdit($event)"
      strip-br="true"
      required>Change me!</div>

    <hr>
    <textarea ng-model="userContent"></textarea>

  </form>
</div>
```

### code: js

```
angular.module('customControl', []).
controller('mainControl', function($scope) {
    $scope.enableEdit = function(e) {
        $(e.target).attr('contenteditable', '');
    }
})
.directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('keyup change', function() {
          scope.$apply(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser
          // leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
});
```